# onFinish() / onTick() function of CountDownTimer failed to be triggered?

Tags: java, android, handler, countdowntimer, soundpool

I was trying to play a sound.wav using SoundPool, and then use CountDownTimer to control the how long it plays the sound. I ran the code and the sound is playing clearly. The question was that it seems the onFinish / onTick function of CountDownTimer is never triggered at all no matter what "millisInFuture" I inputted (the SoundPool is therefore not stopped at all, and the sound play continuously without stopping). I captured the important details as below:

SoundPool was initialzied as below:

```
SoundPool.Builder builder = new SoundPool.Builder();
        builder.setMaxStreams(37);
        AudioAttributes.Builder attrBuilder = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
        attrBuilder.setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        builder.setAudioAttributes(attrBuilder.build());
        soundPool = builder.build();
```

, and loaded some sound.wav:

```
resId = getResId(instrument, "c5", packageName);
c5 = soundPool.load(ctx, resId, 1);
```

variable values initialized as below:

```
duration = 250;
INTERVAL = 5;
```

code:

```
public void play(long duration, float volume){
    float currentVolume = volume;
    stream = soundPool.play(id, currentVolume, currentVolume, 1, -1, 1f);    // Sound is playing clearly and continuously without stopping
    Log.i("Note.Play","Note now playing id=" + id);    // I can see this in the run/debug log

    new CountDownTimer(duration, INTERVAL) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("CountDownTimer","CountDownTimer now checking the SoundPool to play ");    // I can NOT see this in the run/debug log
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("CountDownTimer","FCountDownTimer now stopping the SoundPool to play");    // I can NOT see this in the run/debug log
            soundPool.stop(stream);
            isIdle = true;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Anyone have idea on what did I do wrongly? Or anything I can check to know why?

**Late Update:** 
I just find out the failure was because I put a while loop in Main() thread to receive status of "isIdle" (so as to detect whether the sound is finished playing or not). So is there any way for void play(,) function to inform the Main() thread that the CountDownTimer is done and please proceed to play the next sound?

Thanks.

Comment: and without `soundPool.play()` everything is ok? you see `"CountDownTimer"` logs?

Comment: When I removed soundPool.play(), I still cannot see any log from "CountDownTimer". Really strange...

Comment: Also is there any way for void play(,) function to inform the Main() thread that the CountDownTimer is done and please proceed to play the next sound?

Comment: I just find out the failure was because I put a while loop in Main() thread to receive status of "isIdle". So is there any way for void play(,) function to inform the Main() thread that the CountDownTimer is done and please proceed to play the next sound?